# How to see updated list without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created an admin control panel that allows me to create, edit and delete sets of data from a local API and then display the data as cards on the panel page.

The create, edit and delete features all work successfully. The edit and delete features allow me to use the functions and they display the updated list on the page without me having to refresh the page physically.

The code for the edit and delete features are as follows:

```
deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    axios
      .delete(apiVideoUrl, {})
      .then((response: any) => {
        this.setState({
          adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }


editProduct(id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;

    axios
      .put(apiVideoUrl, {
        title: title,
        url: url,
        thumbnail: thumbnail
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

The code for the create function is as follows:

```
createVideoProduct(title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/`;

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState(({ adminhelpcard }) => ({
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.concat(result)
          }));
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }
```

I have used a event.preventDefault(); function that prevents the page from refreshing after submitting my create function. The card is successfully created as the API is updated, but the card does not display onto the list until I physically refresh the page.

The state for the cards being created is as follows:

```
interface State {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
  thumbnail: string;
  isEditProduct: boolean;
  isAddProduct: boolean;
  id: string;
  whichRadioSelected: string;
}
interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}
```

As far as my knowledge goes, the code should be successfully doing what it's intending to but I can't seem to understand why it isn't working.

Thank you in advance for the support.

------------------EDIT--------------------------

I have added the loadAdminHelpCard function and tried to call this on my clickHandler and my button onClick but it didn't seem to work either.

```
loadAdminHelpCard = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const adminhelpcard = prevState.adminhelpcard;
          return {
            adminhelpcard: [...prevState.adminhelpcard, ...res.data],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: what `result` argument contains in `then` block  in `createVideoProduct`?

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Can you please clarify what you mean by this?

Comment: what type of data server returns to you when you successfully send `POST` request?

Comment: @AndriiGolubenko Do you mean the data from the API? If so then it returns the title,url,thumbnail url and Id as a AdminHelpCard which is an array of singleAdminHelpCard's. If not, then I'm unsure what you mean. I'm new to JS so a lot of this is unfamiliar to me –

Answer (score 1):

it is possible that you did not actually return the data after creating the product, or you are returning an empty array. when you refreshing the page the get method( it is not shown here) that you use to fetch the data will give you the whole query. so make sure you return a valid array after creating a `videoProduct`. you can valid your answer by `console.log(result)` and see for your self that it is returning the data.

and you can simplify just doing

```
createVideoProduct(title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/`;

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    title,
    url,
    thumbnail
  })
};

fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({ adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.concat(result) });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  );
```

}

no need to wrap your `setState` as you did, and additional use eslint; it is a tool that helps us to understand errors.

Comment: I tried to return the data by re-calling my list of cards, but that didn't seem to work. Also, your certificate code doesn't work for me.  I get the following error

"Argument of type '{ certificate: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'State | ((prevState: Readonly<State>"

Comment: what did you get for the response? when you log the result ? console.log(result) ? and please make sure that you use adminhelpcard for replace the certificate . it was a mistake by myside i tested your code using those variables .

Comment: Where exactly would I call this log?

Comment: in `createVIdeoProduct -> fetch().then().then(result) ` console.log the result ,  you can log before the setting state ,  `fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => { console.log(result);
      this.setState({ adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.concat(result) });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  );`

Comment: I got this as a result
```{title: "hi there", url: "www.google.com", thumbnail: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Um3BhY0oS2c/hqdefault.jpg", id: 7}
id: 7
thumbnail: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Um3BhY0oS2c/hqdefault.jpg"
title: "hi there"
url: "www.google.com"
__proto__: Object```

Comment: this result is not equal to the reference SingleAdminHelpCard right ? so insted of binding the whole result do this : `const { title , url , thumbnail } = result ; newData = [{ title , url , thumbnail }] ; this.setState({ adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.concat(newData) });` make sure you are passing exact object as you expected by SingleAdminHelpCard  ; otherwise it will not get update.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show where this would go? would the const be outside the create function?